# Prove that if $k\mid q_1...q_n$ then we can find $k_i$ such that $k=k_1...k_n$ and for every $i$, $k_i\mid q_i$

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic, prime-factorization

Let $k=8$ and $q_1=12$, $q_2=2, q_3=5$. We note that $k\mid q_1q_2q_3$, but $k\nmid q_1$ and $k\nmid q_2$ and $k\nmid q_3$.
Also

$$
8=k_1k_2k_3=4*2*1,
$$

where $k_1\mid q_1$, $k_2\mid q_2$, and $k_3\mid q_3$.

**I want to prove that if $k\mid q_1...q_n$, then we can find $k_i$ such that $k=k_1...k_n$ and for every $i$ holds $k_i\mid q_i$,** like in the example of the beginning.

---

My idea is to descompose every $q_i$ in prime numbers by the Fundamental theorem of aritmethic. Then

$$
q_1...q_n=p_1^{a_1}...p_s^{a_s}.
$$

So if $k\mid q_1...q_n$, then

$$
k=p_1^{b_1}..p_s^{b_s}
$$

and

$$
0\leq b_i\leq a_i.
$$

Now I know every $q_i$ is a combination of powers of $p_i$ so if want to make a $k_i$ such that $k_i\mid q_i$, the $k_i$ should be a combination of this $p_i$ and its exponent should be less than $b_i$, let's call it $c_{i,j}$. Then $\sum_{j=1} c_{i,j}=b_i$.
(Do I make myself clear?)

In the example
$$q_1\cdot q_2\cdot q_3=(2^2\cdot 3)\cdot(2)\cdot(5)=2^3\cdot3\cdot5$$
then
$$8=2^{b_1}\cdot3^{b_2}\cdot5^{b_3}$$
Obviously by the FTA $b_1=3$, $b_2=0$, $b_3=0$

Note $q_1$ and $q_2$ has powers of $2$ then we need $c_{1,1}$ and $c_{1,2}$

$c_{1,1}=2$ and $c_{1,2}=1$ and it verify $c_{1,1}+c_{1,2}=2+1=3=b_1$

Then

$k_1=2^{c_{1,1}}\cdot 3^{b_2}=2^2\cdot3^0=4$

$k_2=2^{c_{1,2}}=2^1=2$

$k_3=5^{b_3}=5^0=1$

---

I don't know how to make more clear my proof or if it is incorrect or just I don't proof anything. Can you help me please?

Comment: It is easier to prove it for $n=2$ and then by induction on $n.$

Comment: This has more to do with number theory than it does, group theory.

Comment: Are we in $\mathbb{N}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}$) or over any ring?

Comment: @Shaun I will use it to prove the converse for Lagrange's Theorem for finite abelian groups

Comment: @NerdOnTour in $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: One can use Bézout's Theorem for many group-theoretic theorems, for example; that doesn't make it a group theory result.

Comment: @Shaun thank you, I'll keep it in mind

Comment: A small quibble with the general statement in the title: if you expand your specific example by one factor, let $q_4=7$, then I think you have to add $k_4=1$. If you are allowed to add as many $1$s as you please to your list of $k_i$ as you add more prime factors $q_i$ to make the statement true, it's not a very strong assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to prove for $n=2$ and then by induction on $n.$

If $k\mid q_1q_2,$ then let $k_1=\gcd(k,q_1).$ Then $$\frac k{k_1}\mid\frac{q_1}{k_1}q_2,\\\gcd\left(\frac k{k_1},\frac {q_1}{k_1}\right)=1,$$ so $$\frac k{k_1}\mid q_2.$$

So letting $k_2=k/k_1,$ we get our result.

The induction step is easy.

---

The above argument uses the results:

> **Result 1:** If $a,b$ are non-zero integers then $$\gcd\left(\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)},\frac b{\gcd(a,b)}\right)=1.$$

And:

> **Result 2:** If $u,v,w$ are integers such that $u\mid vw$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1$ then $u\mid w.$

Both of these can be proven by Bèzout’s identity.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: You mean $gcd\left(\frac k{k_1},\frac {q_1}{k_1}\right)=1$ right?

Answer (score 0):

We can generalize this as follows: if

$$x_1 \cdot \cdots x_m = y_1 \cdot \cdots y_n$$

then there exists $a_{ij}$ such that
$$x_i = \prod_j a_{ij} \\
y_j = \prod_i a_{ij}$$

In other words, there exists a matrix $(a_{ij})$ such that the $x_i$'s are the row products and $y_j$'s are the column products.

Now, if we were working in a commutative group, that would be trivial.  But it also works in $(\mathbb{N}, +)$, $(\mathbb{N}_{+}, \cdot)$ or products of them. An illuminating proof for $(\mathbb{N}_{+}, \cdot)$ can be had using [Schreier refinement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier_refinement_theorem) for the group $\mathbb{Z}/N$, with $N = x_1 \cdots x_m = y_1 \cdots y_n$,  that also provides directly a formula for the $a_{ij}$